# Extensive merging of cells - LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have the following kind of cells and I want to merge them but I want to do it extensively. How can I achieve that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **extensively**? Can you include a picture of what it looks like after the merge? Note: You can only do rectangular merges not L-shaped merges.

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited my question.

Comment: Ah. I can't think of an easy automated way to do that ... are all the other cells always empty? It's probably scriptable but I wouldn't know where to start.